# "Contextual Menu Items" folder missing on my Mac.

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, shortcut-menu

I just can't find the folder "Contextual Menu Items" on my Mac.

I tried these paths :

/Library/Contextual Menu Items

/System/Library/Contextual Menu Items

/Users/nnnn/Library/Contextual Menu Items

Nothing found.

I didn't use "Disk Utility's Repair Disk Permissions feature lately".

Thanks for your anwers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know exactly what's going on:

*...drum roll...*

**You don't have that folder.**

If you need it, you can just create it.

Comment: The problem is I am supposed to find a specific file in this folder. (I encountered this problem when I wanted to modify my contextual menu).

Comment: Usually you just put things in this folder. What do you need to find?